# Does Entity Framework supports multiple ORM databases at a time?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Does Entity Framework support multiple databases? I have two databases, `MySQL` and `SQL Server`, in my solution. If I run one at a time, it is working, but both at the same time are not working.Here is the code. In entity framework `web config` i need to add another settings for mysql, but how?

```
<entityFramework> 
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
  <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: The answer is yes and no. It supports multiple databases, but you won't have a single DbContext communicating the two type of database you have. You have to build two contexts with their connection strings (I suggest to have them in separated projects) and you can instantiate both context in your business logic.

Comment: but <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> creating problem here.How to add both mysql and sql server connection setting here.@SayusiAndo

Comment: That is why I wrote that you need a project for your MySQL stuff and another one for MS SQL. Both project will have its app.config where you can define the needed connectionFactory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a solution having 3 projects:
MsSQLContext
MySQLContext
BusinessLogic

**MsSQLContext project**

Install EF and setup the connection string following [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html).

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySqlContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
        connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Add a class and give a meaningful name for it.

```
    public class MyBusinessContextWithMySQL : DbContext
    {
        public MyBusinessContextWithMySQL() : base("name=MySqlContext")
        {
            this.DisableLazyLoad();
        }

    // Add your entities and mappings here
    }
```

**MySQLContext project**

Install EF and setup the connection string for Ms SQL which is provided by default. Give a name for it and you will have something similar like below:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="MSSQLContext" connectionString="...valid conn string..." />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Add a class and give a meaningful name for it.

```
    public class MyBusinessContextWithMSSQL : DbContext
    {
        public MyBusinessContextWithMSSQL() : base("name=MSSQLContext")
        {
            this.DisableLazyLoad();
        }

    // Add your entities and mappings here
    }
```

**BusinessLogic project**

Install EF and add both connection string to app.config file. You will something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="MSSQLContext" connectionString="...valid conn string..." />
        <add name="MySqlContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mycontext;uid=root;password=********"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

Create a class containing your business logic. Add the two projects above as reference to this project. In your classes where you implement your business logic you can access both context something like below (the code is top of my head and haven't checked whether it is fine or not).

```
public class BusinessLogic{

    public void SomeMethod() {

        // doing stuff with data in MS SQL
        using(MyBusinessContextWithMSSQL msSqlContext = new MyBusinessContextWithMSSQL()) {
            // your business logic
        }

        // doing stuff with data in MySQL
        using(MyBusinessContextWithMySQL msSqlContext = new MyBusinessContextWithMySQL()) {
            // your business logic
        }    
    }    
}
```

This is one way to manage data in both database. It has its own costs, for example: you have to maintain two sets of entities (I assume you have the same data in both).